# Pandas - Searching a string in column A and adding it to the new column B

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

Given I have a column "Name" from "train" dataset, I want to extract the title from it, adding it to the new created column "Title".
[image]

I thought about using `re.search("([A-Za-z]+)\.")` but I am not sure how to loop over the whole column and pass it to the new column afterwards.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Show the "full" code what you tried thus-far...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'],['Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley'],
            ['Heikkinen, Miss. Laina'],['Futrellem, Mrs. Jacques Heath'],
            ['Allen, Mr. William Henry']],
            columns=['Name'])

df['title']=df['Name'].apply(lambda s:s.split(',')[1].split('.')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

df - your dataframe with column Name

```
df["Title"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda name: re.search(name, "([A-Za-z]+).").group(0))
```

it will create new column Title in your df